# linux, write() system call returns -1 while attempting to write to file

Tags: c, linux

In the below program write() returns -1 while writing to a file.

```
   #include<sys/types.h>
   #include<sys/stat.h> 
   #include<fcntl.h>   
   #include<stdio.h>   
   #include<unistd.h> 
   #include<stdlib.h>
   int main() {

   int fd_r=0,fd_w=0;
   int w_ret=100;
   fd_r = open("reader.txt", O_RDONLY);

   fd_w = open("writer.txt",O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);

   char *buf = (char *)malloc(50);

   while(read(fd_r,buf,30))
   {

          w_ret =   write(fd_w,buf,30);
          printf("%d", w_ret);
   }
}
```

Questions: I am unable to debug why this is happening. Correction of code and suggestions as to how to debug such issues are highly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe that `O_CREAT` is valid by itself for the flags: try `O_CREAT | O_WRONLY`.

One way to debug would be checking that the fd_w file descriptor is valid when you first open it.

"The parameter flags is one of O_RDONLY, O_WRONLY or O_RDWR which request opening the file read-only, write-only or read/write, respectively, bitwise-or'd with zero or more of the following..." http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man2/open.2.php

Comment: If you don't specify any read/write flags then `O_RDONLY` is assumed, since its value is `0`.

Comment: which isn't very useful for a file opened for writing ;)

Comment: This seems like the most likely.

Answer (score 3):

at the top of your program

```
#include <errno.h>
```

when your **open** or **read** returns -1, print the value of errno (defined in errno.h), then look in errno.h for what that error means (you will need this throughout your C life, so I gave you all of this rather than just the solution to this problem)

Comment: no, write returns -1 on all errors and an integer value greater than or equal to 0 on success. errno will contain the reason for the failure.

Comment: You **cannot** declare `extern int errno;` or your program has undefined behavior (most likely, a compile-time error, thankfully). `errno.h` defines `errno` and you must use its definition.

Comment: @R.. on linux errno.h declares errno as an extern int, so there is no problem redeclaring it

Comment: @PiedPiper: You're wrong on two levels. First, writing code that's gratuitously specific to a particular implementation and breaks on others is just a stupid idea. And second, the last time any userspace implementation on Linux declared `errno` like that was probably around 1998, 12 years ago. Maybe you mean the Linux kernelspace headers, but I doubt they even have an `errno`.

Comment: despite the error of declaring errno "extern int", this is still the right thing to do in principle. The OP should check errno.

Comment: Edited to reflect current usage and definitions of errno

Comment: @PiedPiper  No, linux does not declare errno as extern int.  Think about how that would work for a multithreaded program. errno is a define for a function call on linux

Comment: Why not just print `strerror(errno)`? And, if you `#include <errno.h>` then it is incorrect `extern int errno`.

Comment: ok I was wrong. I took a quick look at /usr/include/errno.h and missed the '#ifndef errno' around 'extern int errno'

Answer (score 1):

If you add some error handling, you can learn more. e.g.

```
  #include<sys/types.h>
   #include<sys/stat.h>
   #include<fcntl.h>
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<unistd.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   int main() {

   int fd_r=0,fd_w=0;
   int w_ret=100;
   fd_r = open("reader.txt", O_RDONLY);
   if(fd_r == -1)
     perror("fd_r open");

   fd_w = open("writer.txt",O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
   if(fd_w == -1)
     perror("fd_w open");

   char *buf = (char *)malloc(50);

   while(read(fd_r,buf,30))
   {

          w_ret =   write(fd_w,buf,30);
          if(w_ret == -1) {
            perror("write");
            break;
          }
          printf("%d", w_ret);
   }
}
```

When run , if "reader.txt" does not exist:

```
$ ./a.out
fd_r open: No such file or directory
write: Bad file descriptor
```

I.e. not surprisingly, open() failed because the file is missing.

When run, and "reader.txt" does exist:

```
$ ./a.out
write: Bad file descriptor
```

This is a bit more subtle, but the documentation for write (`man 2 write`) says:

> *EBADF*  fd is not a valid file
>   descriptor or is not open for writing.

Well. open() didn't fail, so we do have a valid file descriptor. So it's "is not open for writing."

And indeed:

```
 open("writer.txt",O_CREAT,S_IRWXU);
```

Should be:

```
  open("writer.txt",O_CREAT|O_WRONLY,S_IRWXU);
```